# VBA text file parsing

Tags: parsing, vba, text

I have to figure out a way to parse a text file in VBA this week and I was hoping I could get some guidance on how this would work.

The fileformat is similar to the example below (2 lines per relevant entry with no delimiters).  Individual records are determined by the positions on the line:

```
005839998000017868XC9089
  002598DD930120000000000
```

My question is how could I tell ExcelVBA to to import characters 1-6 as an entry and 8-12 as another, etc?  Then, how can I make sure that it is looking at every two lines as a related record?  I then have to export each record on a line in some type of delimited file.

Any guidance on how to get started will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So are you reading from a text file and then immediately writing out to a different one, or are we involving a spreadsheet at some point?

Comment: I would prefer to immediately write out to another text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of your question is answered in this other question [Read lines from a text file but skip the first two lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938796/vba-read-lines-from-text-file-exclude-top-two-lines)

If you end up with a line in a string, you can use the `mid()` to break out individual fields and the `left()` function to tell you what kind of line you are on.