# VBA Match Worksheet Names to Text List

Tags: vba

I Have a text list of city names and I need to check and see if those names are the names of worksheets and if not create a new worksheet with the said name.

On the other side if there are any worksheets without a name on the list then I need to delete those worksheets.

I've been trying this problem for a few hours and am very lost, its probably something simple, so if someone can help that would be very appreciated!

Comment: can you show what you've tried? if you import that text list into a type of collection that you can loop through, i'd imagine it be rather easy.

Comment: I dont have any code for what I've tried because everything I have tried has broken horribly. I have been trying to do two for loops inside of each other, one looking at the city names in the cells and one flipping through sheets but I cannot find an efficient way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's just about what a code for this would look like. Here's what my text file looks like so there are no confusions.

[image]

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim sFileName, tmp As String
Dim dict As New Dictionary
Dim dictCopy As New Dictionary
Dim ws As Worksheet

sFileName = "C:\Users\Mango\Desktop\names.txt"
'^ Specify the location of the txt file that you want read

    With New Scripting.FileSystemObject
        With .OpenTextFile(sFileName, ForReading)

            Do Until .AtEndOfStream
                tmp = .ReadLine
                '^ This step should be noted. Calling .Readline more than once
                '  even in loop cause it to move to the next one.

                dict.Add tmp, tmp
                dictCopy.Add tmp, tmp
                '^ add to our dictionary objects
            Loop

        End With
    End With
```

This is a text reading code that I picked up form here: [Read lines from a text file but skip the first two lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938796/read-lines-from-a-text-file-but-skip-the-first-two-lines). I find it more elegant than other vba text reading code. But you need to have a "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" selected as a reference (from the tools menu) to use it. This code also makes use of the `Dictionary` object which also requires that reference to use it. I used this object as opposed to an array or other collection for reasons that I will explain below.

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If dict.Exists(ws.Name) = True Then
        dict.Remove (ws.Name)
   End If
Next

For Each j In dict.Items
    Set ws = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
    ws.Name = j
Next
```

Depending on how long your list is you might find the `Dictionary` object favorable to double looping and the like. This is because it has the `.Exists` method to see if it contains a specific value within itself. I don't know the mechanics inside it, but it is **MUCH** faster than the double looping technique, especially when you have a lot of entries to compare to. You should note that alot of these dictionary methods make use of the keys info (and not values).

Final part:

```
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'removes annoying save notification
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If dictCopy.Exists(ws.Name) = False Then
            ws.Delete
        End If
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I chose to do it like this because excel will not allow you to delete the last sheet in a workbook. So if you chose to delete the wrongly named sheets or at least combine the method, you might run into issues if none of the sheet names mactches those in the collection all of them must be deleted.

Comment: Wow, that is extremely helpful for the future but it was not what I was looking for, I should have been more clear, the text list is in cells within excel and not in a .txt function, however that is insanely useful and i will keep that saved for future reference.

Comment: the above can still apply. if your list is in any column or contiguous cells, you could easily loop through to fill the collections instead. you not posting any code isn't helping us either.

Comment: Just looked at it again, totally makes sense how I can convert it, i guess just seeing the Dictionary terms being used i spaced and didn't think it could function with excel. Thanks Mango!